# How can I disable a crafting table so that players cannot interact with it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a Minecraft map with crafting tables as decorations. Players will be using Emeralds to craft items, so I do not want players to be able to use Crafting tables at all.

Is there a way you can make certain crafting tables unable to open their GUI?

Comment: I'd suggest making a texture pack that puts the crafting bench texture on a non-interactive block.  There's no good way to prevent a player from opening the crafting bench.

Comment: A server plugin could easily do this, but for vanilla this seems to be a tough challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any way to disable a real crafting table, but you could summon a falling block that looks like one:

```
/summon minecraft:leash_knot ~ ~ ~ {Tags:[{"blockCenter"}]}
/execute @e[tag=blockCenter] ~ ~ ~ summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Block:crafting_table,NoGravity:1,Time:1,CustomName:fakeCraftingTable}
```

Then use a repeating command block to run:

```
/entitydata @e[name=fakeCraftingTable] {Time:1}
```

To make sure it never despawns. You can put a block with a smaller 'footprint', like a cake, in that spot to make it appear solid.

Comment: In fiddling around with other commands, I accidentally discovered another solution: surround a crafting table with piston extension blocks. They're and invisible and don't block movement, but they prevent you from using a block viewed through them. Stand in any spot next to the crafting table that's not filled by another block and run /setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:piston_extension. Keep in mind though, they prevent building in that spot, block liquids, and can only be destroyed by commands.